# How to add pagelines to a EditText in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, underline

Is it possible to show pagelines in a `EditText`?

I mean these lines:

[image]

Let's say my `EditText` is 500 by 500 pixels in size. I want those lines to be visible across that 500 by 500 square.

Is there a build in way to do this? I already tried Google but I couldn't find an answer.
I guess my other option is to dynamically create a graphic based on the textheight and linespacing, such an ugly work-around.

Comment: You need lines like a notepad in your edit text correct? (NOT the notepad graphic like background itself?)

Comment: It's like this: I have a graphic of a notepad like the one in my example, only without the lines. If I put the lines in the graphic itself the lines will never totally sync with the text because the image is scaled to fit screen height (the font-size should stay the same). That's why I don't want to solve this by using a background, but for the `EditText` itself.

Comment: Then my answer should work for you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The notepad application sample from the android dev site shows you how to do this.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html

Looks like this (scroll down for code):

> [image: Notepad]

Most of the relevant code is in [this file](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/src/com/example/android/notepad/NoteEditor.html). Pay attention to the `LinedEditText` inner class. It is defined within the activity. It draws the lines required.

Inside the activity `onCreate()` method, `setContentView(R.id.note_editor)` is set as the view, it is defined like [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/res/layout/note_editor.html)

Snippet extracted from [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/src/com/example/android/notepad/NoteEditor.html). **Update**: Code modified by @Pieter888 to draw lines on the entire `EditText` control.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class LinedEditText extends EditText 
{
    private Rect mRect;
    private Paint mPaint;

    public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        mRect = new Rect();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFF000000);
    }

    /**
     * This is called to draw the LinedEditText object
     * @param canvas The canvas on which the background is drawn.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        int height = canvas.getHeight();
        int curHeight = 0;
        Rect r = mRect;
        Paint paint = mPaint;
        int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);
        for (curHeight = baseline + 1; curHeight < height; 
                                                 curHeight += getLineHeight())
        {
            canvas.drawLine(r.left, curHeight, r.right, curHeight, paint);
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working pretty good for me now, I'm currently editing the `LinedEditText` to show multiple lines even on empty lines (So it fills the screen)

Comment: Thanks a lot! If you update your answer with this code: http://pastebin.com/sJBJtxbR I can accept your answer. I've made a small edit in the code which makes the lines repeat trough the whole `LinedEditText`-view.

Comment: @Pieter888 Updated :) You can always feel free to add findings of your own as a highlighted update into your question too. Cheers!

Comment: How can i get text from this view?
I want to save all the text as a text file and save in sd card.

Comment: it was not showing more lines..in the sense if im entering more text after some extent it was not showing line but allowing to enter text

Comment: @gideon it's not drawing more lines when height of edittext increases. how can that be solved?

Comment: @Ramz i found a way to solve this. check answer below

Comment: Here is the updated link for [Google's NotePad Sample](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/05523fb0b48280a5364908b00768ec71edb847a2/samples/NotePad/src/com/example/android/notepad/NoteEditor.java). Check line#78 for the `LinedEditText `.

Answer (score 1):

@gideon's answer above works well but has an issue when you enter more text in the `edittext` because more lines are not drawn accordingly. To solve this, I wrote an override for `onMeasure()` and called `invalidate()`. and more lines will be drawn when text increases.

```
  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec,heightMeasureSpec);
    invalidate();
  }
```

The code now is:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class LinedEditText extends EditText 
{
    private Rect mRect;
    private Paint mPaint;

    public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        mRect = new Rect();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFF000000);
    }

    /**
     * This is called to draw the LinedEditText object
     * @param canvas The canvas on which the background is drawn.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        int height = canvas.getHeight();
        int curHeight = 0;
        Rect r = mRect;
        Paint paint = mPaint;
        int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);
        for (curHeight = baseline + 1; curHeight < height; 
                                                 curHeight += getLineHeight())
        {
            canvas.drawLine(r.left, curHeight, r.right, curHeight, paint);
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

 @Override
 protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
   super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec,heightMeasureSpec);
   invalidate();
      }
}
```

Comment: This is so old.. interesting how it got dug up. Didn't quite think of that case and I'm quite far from android now :) Good job on your update ! :) +1

Answer (score 0):

@gideon's code works but more lines not be drawn

you must just change `canvas.getHeight()` to `getHeight()` as following below:

```
public class LinedEditText extends EditText
 {
private Rect mRect;
private Paint mPaint;

public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    mRect = new Rect();
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.blue,null));
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    int height = getHeight();
    int curHeight = 0;
    Rect r = mRect;
    Paint paint = mPaint;
    int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);
    for (curHeight = baseline + 1; curHeight < height;
         curHeight += getLineHeight())
    {
        canvas.drawLine(r.left, curHeight, r.right, curHeight, paint);
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```