# Android: Making beautiful EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want design an android app. Such as this:

[image]

That user can write on this, I designed it by android widget UI, but How can I do it like this beautiful? 
Please help me

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992411/how-to-add-pagelines-to-a-edittext-in-android

Comment: i used it, and lines are ok! but how can set an image behind it??

Comment: take another layout which has full width height. set that image as background. You can use relative layout to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at your example:

You could change the color of the actionbar.

You could set the background of your android textedit transparent, and set a custom font.

```
 android:background="@null"
```

Then, on the background of your view, you can set the image of a notepad.

And for the buttons on the buttom, make custom buttons : http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/android-custom-button

There are also many open source note-taking apps where you can take a look at.

(Sorry for bad markup, I'm typing this on my phone)

Answer (score 0):

top bar of app is an actionbar. see this links for how to use:

[android actionbar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

[Actionbar sample](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html)

pins at top of paper is an image. use ImageView.

the paper that user can write on it try this link:

[Android Notepad](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html)

footer of app is a panel and buttons.